# No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/movieshub

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is my connection string

```
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
  String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/movieshub";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
```

It was working just fine before but now its giving an error : driver not found even though I do have jar file(mysql connector) in library folder as well

Answer (score 0):

I added derbyclient.jar file for jdk folder and it works fine now